# How do I use a core class from an external script?

Tags: nodes, 9, external-scripts

I am trying to access a node programmatically and getting errors though using (AFAIK) the recommended way.

My code (so far) is really simple.

```php
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;

$nid=1805;
$node = Node::load($nid);
print_r($node, true);
```

It keeps failing with this error message.

> [09-Nov-2020 08:32:31 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Drupal\node\Entity\Node' not found in test-node-access.php

The program resides (at least currently) in Drupal root directory. I am acting on user action via AJAX call from a paragraph (as a lame explanation to a little un-orthodox implementation).

Comment: For bootstrapping Drupal for an external script: [How can I bootstrap?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/269235/how-can-i-bootstrap) ([2nd example](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/286756/how-to-bootstrap-a-custom-script-and-retrieve-the-session-object)) (this is NOT the recommended method for Ajax requests within Drupal itself!)

Comment: Yes, definitely not recommend. Instead of a single PHP file define a route pointing at a controller which returns a response in the format the AJAX call is expecting.

Comment: Yep, I will do it with a proper controller